# You have an error in your SQL syntax with table and connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im getting this error, I can't figure out why thought:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Case (clientforename, clientsurname) VALUES ('ghghgj', 'ffhhf')' at line 1

this is the php code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Case (clientforename, clientsurname)
VALUES ('$clientforename', '$clientsurname')")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please don't tag MySQL questions with SQL Server.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Case` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You must wrap it in ticks:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Case` (clientforename, clientsurname)
VALUES ('$clientforename', '$clientsurname')")
or die(mysql_error());
```